# Sum of all the columns of a rows in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I find out the sum of certain columns of a row in MySQL using Laravel?

I know `->sum('something');` gives you the sum of a column. But what about a row?

Is there any method to do so in Laravel?

Currently I'm adding each column values manually and getting the sum.

Comment: There is no built in way. Do you really want the sum of all columns or just *some* columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but you can write a function yourself. Well, actually, I did that already for you! ;)

You have two options. The boring one, a function that just returns a predefined sum:

```
public function getSum(){
    return $this->value1 + $this->value2; // and so on
}
```

Or a *generic* function that you can place inside a `BaseModel` and use in every class and with every attributes you want:

```
public function getAttributeSum(){
    $sum = 0;
    foreach(func_get_args() as $attribute){
        $sum += $this->getAttribute($attribute);
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
$model->getAttributeSum('value1', 'value2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a model function and pass all the variables to it and do the calculation there. Then return the total and print wherever you want it.

```
{{Classmodel::total($yourvariablearray)}}
```

In the `Classmodel.php` you will have something like:

```
public static function total($variablearray){
  return $total = $variablearray->columnone +  $variablearray->columntwo;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

> return \DB::table('table_name')->sum('column_to_be_calculated');

Works for laravel 5 .